# Merge multiple objects with Sanctuary.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, sanctuary

I am trying to merge multiple objects with Sanctuary.

With Ramda.js I would do something like this (see the REPL [here](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20initialEntry%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%200%2C%20b%3A%201%20%7D%3B%0Aconst%20entries%20%3D%20%5B%7Bc%3A%202%7D%2C%20%7Bd%3A%203%2C%20e%3A%204%7D%2C%20%7Bf%3A%205%2C%20g%3A%206%2C%20h%3A%207%7D%5D%3B%0AR.reduce%28Object.assign%2C%20initialEntry%2C%20entries%29%3B%0A)):

```
const R = require('ramda');
const initialEntry = { a: 0, b: 1 };
const entries = [{c: 2}, {d: 3, e: 4}, {f: 5, g: 6, h: 7}];
R.reduce(Object.assign, initialEntry, entries);
```

However, with Santuary.js the following line of code throws an exception.

```
S.reduce(Object.assign)(initialEntry)(entries)
```

Here is the exception I am getting:

```
! Invalid value

reduce :: Foldable f => (a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a
                              ^^^^^^
                                1

1)  {"a": 0, "b": 1} :: Object, StrMap Number, StrMap FiniteNumber, StrMap Integer, StrMap NonNegativeInteger, StrMap ValidNumber

The value at position 1 is not a member of ‘b -> a’.
```

I am puzzled by this error message. Am I using `S.reduce` incorrectly? Also, I get no errors if I write `S.reduce(Object.assign)(initialEntry)([])`.

Comment: In case it helps find a similar function in Sanctuary; I would use [`mergeAll`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeAll) in Ramda to merge a list of objects.

Comment: ... and `unapply(mergeAll)` for a variadic version closer to `Object.assign`.

Comment: Or possibly ˋunapply(Object.assign)ˋ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the first argument to `reduce` takes a function with the signature `a -> b -> a`.  Unlike Ramda, Sanctuary is strict about such signatures.  You have to supply it a function that takes an argument of one type and returns a function that takes an argument of a second type and returns an argument of the first type.  `Object assign` does not do that.  It takes a variable number of objects in one go.

You can fix this by replacing `Object.assign` with `a => b => Object.assign(a, b)`:

```js
const initialEntry = { a: 0, b: 1 };
const entries = [{c: 2}, {d: 3, e: 4}, {f: 5, g: 6, h: 7}];

const res = S.reduce(a => b => Object.assign(a, b)) (initialEntry) (entries);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/sanctuary@1.0.0"></script>
<script>const S = sanctuary</script>
```

The Ramda version works because it expects a binary function to `reduce`.  While `Object.assign` is technically variadic, everything works fine if you treat it like a binary function.

Answer (score 1):

`S.concat` can be specialized to `StrMap a -> StrMap a -> StrMap a`. As a result, the type of `S.reduce (S.concat) ({})` is `Foldable f => f (StrMap a) -> StrMap a`. This can be specialized to `Array (StrMap a) -> StrMap a`. For example:

```
> S.reduce (S.concat) ({}) ([{a: 0, b: 1}, {c: 2}, {d: 3, e: 4}, {f: 5, g: 6, h: 7}])
{a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7}
```

Sanctuary does not provide a function for merging *arbitrary* objects.